# bad file descriptor when using write() function

Tags: c, file, file-descriptor

I want to write a program that transfers simultaneously more files. At a point I received bad file descriptor error.
What I've done?
I have all the files in decreasing order by their size ( I open them in this order and f->filename[i] doesn't change). 
    I modified the permissions for those files: chmod ugo+wrx .
    When a file is completely sent then I decrement the numberOfFiles after "for".
    My problem is that when I want to write into a file it return bad file descriptor, but when I want to close that file it works fine.

Here is the piece of code that doesn't work:

```
//open all the files that I want to send
        f->fileIndex[i] = open(f->fileName[i],O_RDONLY | O_CREAT);
        if (f->fileIndex[i] < 0 ) {
          perror("ERROR: Cannot open/create the file \n");
        }
....
for (i=1; i<numberOfFiles; ++i){
          if (write(f->fileIndex[i],aux,sz) == -1) {
            perror("ERROR Cannot write\n");
          }
          printf("%d %s\n",f->fileIndex[i],aux);
// aux = what I want to write
...
          if (f->size[i] <= 0) { //If the whole file was sent
            printf("close the file  %s\n",f->fileName[i]);
            if (close(f->fileIndex[i])) { // and here it works fine ...
              perror("cannot open the file\n");
            }
          }
}
```

I checked and there it is the same value for file_descriptor.
Could you please where I am wrong, please? 
Any hint will help!
Thanks!

Comment: Try `O_WRONLY` or `O_RDWR` instead of `O_RDONLY`..

Comment: NOTE: don't forget to add a third argument to open(2) if you specify O_CREAT in the 2nd argument. := `fd = open(f->fileName[i],O_RDONLY | O_CREAT, 0644);`

Comment: But if `open()` returns >= 0, the options must be OK, so these can't be the problem. You must be doing something that's overwriting `f->fileIndex[i]`, or you're using an uninitialized element of the array.

Comment: Hi, thank you all. The problem was that I gave O_RDONLY instead of  O_WRONLY. @wildplasser thanks for your advice, now I don't need to use chmod :)